# Copy paste excel to ppt, data on wrong slide

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint, copy-paste

I have the following code. It takes data from excel and pastes it into a PPT template.
As you can see I use `ppSlide` to keep track of which slide I'm currently on. To do so I set the number of the next slide when I'm done with the slide before.

However, when I run the code it pastes the second file on the 2nd slide (should be the 3rd slide). Any ideas as to why?

```
Sub maakPPT()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim wsReoOverzicht As Worksheet
    Dim chPlanning As Chart
    Dim grafPersImp As Range
    Dim wsGrafiek  As Worksheet

    Set wsReoOverzicht = Worksheets("Reo's gestart")
    Set chPlanning = Charts("Planning")
    Set wsGrafiek = Worksheets("Grafiek")
    Set grafPersImp = wsGrafiek.Range("A3:N24")

    'ppt openen
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppApp.Visible = True
    ppApp.Activate

    'template openen 2e slide selecteren
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open("F:\WGD\Dep 456566-Centrale Reorganisatieteam\AAB CRT Algemeen\PMO CRT\Dashboards\ppt presentaties\Template Totaaloverzicht.pptx")
    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(2)

    'Totaal lopende Reo's (planning)
    wsReoOverzicht.ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
    "Lopend"
    chPlanning.CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    ppSlide.Select
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
    ppSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 600
    ppSlide.Shapes(2).Height = 375
    ppSlide.Shapes.Range(2).Align msoAlignCenters, True
    ppSlide.Shapes.Range(2).Align msoAlignMiddles, True
    Set ppSlide = ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(3)

   'Totaal personele impact (grafiek)
   grafPersImp.Copy
   ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
   ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
   ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
   ppSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 400
   ppSlide.Shapes(2).Height = 275
   ppSlide.Shapes.Range(2).Align msoAlignCenters, True
   ppSlide.Shapes.Range(2).Align msoAlignMiddles, True
   Set ppSlide = ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(4)
```

Comment: Any reason you `Set` 2nd slide differently to the way you `Set` 3rd?

Comment: No, saw that myself just now, made it into `Set ppSlide = ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2)`

Answer (score 0):

The difference with the first painting step was that I didn't use `ppSlide.select` to make it the active sheet.